# How to git pull/fetch from repacked upstream?

Tags: git

I've run `git repack -adf --depth=10000 --window=10000` on upstream repo which ran long time and shrinked it from 900 to 600 MB.

Is it possible now to `git-pull`/`git-fetch` this pack changes ( without doing fresh `git-clone` )?

I don't want to do `git-repack` on those clients, because it will take very long time, and creating new repo with `git-clone` doesn't look as **right** option - it creates new repo ( without your config, stash, you later need to move untracked files, etc. ), not just *updates* your current one.

Comment: I don't have any authoritative source for that right now, but by instinct I'd say that how objects are stored (loosely or packed) should be totally transparent to higher-abstraction commands like fetch/push/clone. Do you have an older clone from that repo at hand? Why don't you just try it out?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, local packing does not affect fetch/push (and clone also) in any way. Bundle which is being sent alway packed from scratch. So you cannot really benefit from the on-server repack during fetch or clone.

you can, however, copy `.git/objects/pack/*.pack` files from server to clients and run `git index-pack --stdin --keep=origin <$file` for each of them. Then run `git gc` to remove redundant objects and keep only those which do not exist on the server - it should be fast. See for details https://git-scm.com/docs/git-index-pack